# Apache Tapestry @CommitAfter does not work after redirecting to another page

Tags: java, tapestry

I have the following scenario in `MyPage.java`:

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.Link;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.OnEvent;
import org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.annotations.CommitAfter;

public MyPage {
    @Property
    @Persist
    private SubmitAction submitAction; // an enumeration

    @OnEvent(value = EventConstants.SUCCESS, component = "mainForm")
    Object onSuccessFromMainForm() {
        Link link = null;

        commitSomething();

        if (submitAction != null && this.submitAction.equals(SubmitAction.APPROVE)) {
            link = linkService.getLink(AnotherPage.class, true, "anotherPage");
        } else {
            link = linkService.getLink(MyPage.class, actionId, documentId);
        }

        return link;
    }

    @CommitAfter
    private void commitSomething() {
        // here are some interaction with Dao and Service layers.
    }

    Object onActivate(Long actionId, Long documentId) {
        // url handler
        // do something
        return null;
    }
}
```

The idea is if some conditions are satisfied to link to `AnotherPage`:
`http://localhost:7001/myproject/anotherpage`

Otherwise to stay on the same page with url params: 
`http://localhost:7001/myproject/mypage/678123/567234`

The expected behavior is that the `@CommitAfter` should work in both cases but it works only when the link is to the same page.

Do you have any idea why this can happen?

---

EDIT:

Actually I found a solution - this is not not just a problem with `Apache Tapestry`.
The main problem was with the my business logic which depends on the `onActivate`. On this method `Apache tapestry` failed to set some `@Persist` fields and broke my logic. I added `onPassivate` method and it works fine now.

**I apologize if I've lost your time and thanks for all the answers!**

Comment: it should work regardless, try putting a breakpoint in `org.apache.tapestry5.internal.jpa.CommitAfterMethodAdvice` and trace execution

Answer (score 0):

You can only put the @CommitAfter on a method which is invoked by tapestry. Tapestry doesn't know about your `commitSomething()` method which is private. It can't intercept this method call

Comment: That's not true: Tapestry instruments all methods in page/component classes regardless of their visibility (see `CommitAfterWorker`); it should then be enough to invoke that method from anywhere.

Comment: Hmm... the magic of byte code manipulation. I stand corrected